# Mouse goes off after 2 seconds on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

I downloaded the Ubuntu from gnome, gnome-ubuntu. I have a laptop and I'm new to Linux.

The problem I have is that when connecting a USB mouses it stops working almost immediately. I read that it could be configurations with respect to USB auto-suspend but nothing has worked for me.

I have changed the configuration of both laptop-mode and manually entering the devices. I tried changing the probe seconds from 2 seconds to 10. It does not save the Configuration

I do not know what else to do,. The version is 16.

Edit: Output of `dmesg`:

```
[  799.770548] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[  799.883505] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=15d9, idProduct=0a4c
[  799.883511] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  799.883514] usb 2-1.2: Product:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[  799.886727] input:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:15D9:0A4C.0004/input/input16
[  799.947049] hid-generic 0003:15D9:0A4C.0004: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[  800.700267] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  800.708256] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  800.740257] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  800.748257] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  800.772257] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  800.788248] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  800.876258] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  800.916259] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  800.940295] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  800.956267] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  800.988261] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  801.020261] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  801.028260] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  801.068254] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  801.100289] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  801.108253] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  801.116262] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  801.212270] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  801.357815] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  801.524285] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  803.348302] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[  803.388292] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
```

Comment: I have no idea, but does it work again for another 2 seconds if you unplug it and plug it again? If so I guess I would suspect something wrong with the mouse.

Comment: have u installed laptop-mode-tools?

Comment: Type `dmesg`, remember last line, then plug in USB mouse and watch it stop working, type `dmesg` again. Update your question with all new lines from the output, they may give a hint what goes wrong.

Comment: I'm not using laptop-mode-tools.

Comment: If I unplug and plug its the same result after 2 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I can resolve my problem, It was gnome services, I delete gnome-software-services from /etc/autostart/ with:

```
sudo rm -r gnome-software-service.desktop
```